# Extract an ISBN with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have an extremely long string that I want to parse for a numeric value that occurs after the substring "ISBN". However, this grouping of 13 digits can be arranged differently via the "-" character. Examples: (these are all valid ISBNs) `123-456-789-123-4`, OR `1-2-3-4-5-67891234`, OR `12-34-56-78-91-23-4`. Essentially, I want to use a regex pattern matcher on the potential ISBN to see if there is a valid 13 digit ISBN. How do I 'ignore' the "-" character so I can just regex for a `\d{13}` pattern?  My function:

```
public String parseISBN (String sourceCode) {
  int location = sourceCode.indexOf("ISBN") + 5;
  String ISBN = sourceCode.substring(location); //substring after "ISBN" occurs
  int i = 0;
  while ( ISBN.charAt(i) != ' ' )
    i++;
  ISBN = ISBN.substring(0, i); //should contain potential ISBN value
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{13}"); //this clearly will find 13 consecutive numbers, but I need it to ignore the "-" character
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ISBN); 
  if (matcher.find()) return ISBN;
  else return null;
}
```

Comment: my suggestion would be just replace `-` with nothing. Then use your ISBN checking function. And then if it is correct, you can use either one you need.

Comment: Some good regexes in the answers, and I'd certainly use one because it would catch all valid ISBN formats -- but I just wanted to point out that the dashes in an ISBN aren't arbitrarily inserted; there are only certain combinations that are valid. (Of course you're not trying to validate the form of the number, just get the number)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Alternative 1:

  ```
  pattern.matcher(ISBN.replace("-", ""))
  ```
- Alternative 2: Something like

  ```
  Pattern.compile("(\\d-?){13}")
  ```

**Demo of second alternative:**

```
String ISBN = "ISBN: 123-456-789-112-3, ISBN: 1234567891123";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d-?){13}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ISBN);

while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

**Output:**

```
123-456-789-112-3
1234567891123
```

Comment: You'll be hard pressed to find a better combination of readability and code efficiency. You can make it more efficient, but you'll lose a lot of readability.

Comment: more efficient how so? Im going to be calling this function potentially thousands of times so anything would be helpful...

Comment: Some regular expression can get compiled into nasty back-tracking routines. This one will probably be quite efficient though. The obvious alternative is to go through the string "manually" in a for loop. If you end up comparing the two approaches, please report your results back here... would be interesting to hear about :-)

Comment: Why not use `String.replace("-","");` instead?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Pattern.compile("\\d(-?\\d){12}")
```

Comment: +1 Best answer yet. But I would add a `\b` word boundary anchor on each end.

Answer (score 3):

Use this pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("(?:\\d-?){13}")
```

and strip all dashes from the found isbn number

Answer (score 2):

Do it in one step with a pattern recognizing everything, and optional dashes between digits. No need to fiddle with ISBN offset + substrings.

```
ISBN(\d(-?\d){12})
```

If you want the raw number, strip dashes from the first matched subgroup afterwards.
I am not a Java guy so I won't show you code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be calling the method a lot, the best thing you can do is *not* compile the Pattern inside it.  Otherwise, each time you call the method you'll spend more time *creating* the regex than you will actually searching for it.

But after looking at your code again, I think you have a bigger problem, performance-wise.  All that business of locating "ISBN" and then creating substrings to apply the regex to is completely unnecessary.  Let the regex do that stuff; it's what they're for.  The following regex finds the "ISBN" sentinel *and* the following thirteen digits, if they're there:

```
static final Pattern isbnPattern = Pattern.compile(
    "\\bISBN[^A-Z0-9]*+(\\d(?:-*+\\d){12})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE );
```

The `[^A-Z0-9]*+` gobbles up whatever characters may appear between the "ISBN" and the first digit.  The possessive quantifier (`*+`) prevents needless backtracking; if the next character is not a digit, the regex engine immediately quits that match attempt and resumes scanning for another "ISBN" instance.

I used another possessive quantifier for the optional hyphens, plus a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) for the repeated portion; that gives another slight performance gain over the capturing groups most of the other responders are using.  But I used a capturing group for the whole number, so it can be extracted from the overall match easily.  With these changes, your method reduces to this:

```
public String parseISBN (String source) {
  Matcher m = isbnPattern.matcher(source); 
  return m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
}
```

...and it's much more efficient, too.  Note that we haven't addressed how the strings are getting into memory.  If you're doing the I/O yourself, it's possible there are significant performance gains to be achieved in that area, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can strip out the dashes with string manipulation, or you could use this:

```
"\\b(?:\\d-?){13}\\b"
```

It has the added bonus of making sure the string doesn't start or end with `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Try stripping the dashes out, and regex the new string

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

"(?:[0-9]{9}[0-9X]|[0-9]{13}|[0-9][0-9-]{11}[0-9X]|[0-9][0-9-]{15}[0-9])(?![0-9-])"