# How to parse array returned from php to String array in android

Tags: java, php, android

I get the following response after executing a HTTP post from PHP in Android.

```
new Array("1:Excellent","2:Good","3:Average","4:Not good","5:Disappointing")
```

I want to parse this result to a string array, so that I can fill a spinner with these values.

Comment: Can you change the format of the data sent by the server? If so JSON would be a good format. Also, what does the server sent, if the description contains an `"` character?

Comment: Your server sent you javascript code, which is probably intended to be evaluated using javascript's `eval` function. This is generally considered unsafe, especially if you develop an non-internal application.

Comment: actually I don't have access to the php. All I could do is Android.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487908/how-i-can-use-javascript-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse String with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113603/parse-string-with-regex)

Comment: can you post the exact string you get from the server?

Comment: new Array("1:Excellent","2:Good","3:Average","4:Not good","5:Disappointing"). This is the exact string I am getting

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a string constructor that can take an array but maybe check the Java String documentation.  You could check the Array's size, create a string array of that size, then manually copy in from Array to the String array via a loop value by value. I am not as familiar with copying from an Array object but it would seem you would get the object and typecast to a string. Also i'm not sure i see Array in java collections, i use a few languages,  so if you have not managed to get the data into a java object yet this would not yet apply.

Comment: I don't think that this line is part of his source code but rather the response of the server.

Comment: ya its the response from the server

Comment: in the java code you create a new Array? this would probably apply then i wasn't sure if Array was in the javascript/php or java.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ScriptEngine` with the engine set to Javascript, your code doesn't throw any errors within JS.

[image: No errors]

```
ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").getEngineByName("JavaScript");

String expression = ...; // Get the expression from the web server
String ss[] = (String[]) js.eval(expression);
```

ScriptEngine is available from JDK6+ you can find the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html). You can include javax.script in your Android app, you can find the source for that [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/script)

Comment: ScriptEngine is not available in Android.

Comment: EDIT: Could you not include javax.script package with your Android app? You can get it all from http://grepcode.com/ - I'll include this in my answer.

Comment: finally I found a solution by tokenizing the response using delimiters, it is not the solution I really wanted. But for the time being I am using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void parseJson() {
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    // response to inputstream
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"));

        sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    // to string
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            b.add(json_data.getString("Name"));

        }

    }
```

Declare necessary variables ! use this inside doInBackGround() method of asynctask

Comment: JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result); This line gives error...String can't be converted into JsonArray

Comment: it might mean that the response that you are getting from the url is incorrect...in the catch block after the try block under json exception ... put a line e.printStackTrace(); ..you should discover why the exception has been caught.

Comment: I am getting the above error in the catch block. The php is not sending back response in Json format. Thats the problem here. It is echoing just the array.