# How to parse string with regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

How can I parse such data with Java regex?

```
data.param[0] 
0 - is any non negavite digit
```

Here is my try -

```
String result = Pattern.compile("(data.param[)(\\d+)(])").matcher("data.param[13123]").group();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? [parse String with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113603/parse-string-with-regex)

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? The digit in between the square brackets? The `param[digit]` idiom? Note that your `.` should be double-escaped in the `Pattern`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("data\\.param\\[(\\d+)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("data.param[13123]");

if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Comment: Yes. It's fine solution. Thanks. Will accept it in a 9 mins.